# Foreach duplicating when creating object of objects

Tags: php, foreach

**What I have**

So I have a variable named `result` that is formatted like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => dev1
        [id] => 09A
        [sum] => 52
        [completed_pct_completed] => 97.97
        [completed_pct_1msec] => 11.44
        ....
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => dev1
        [id] => 273
        [sum] => 59
        [completed_pct_completed] => 94.43
        [completed_pct_1msec] => 10.95
        ....
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => dev1.1
        [id] => 28A
        [sum] => 39
        [completed_pct_completed] => 95.55
        [completed_pct_1msec] => 20.78
        ....
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => dev1.1
        [id] => 28B
        [sum] => 31
        [completed_pct_completed] => 91.55
        [completed_pct_1msec] => 28.78
        ....
    )
....
```

There are about 250 different objects. The problem with this current order is that the description of each becomes redundant to the point that I just one want to put all the data of each description into an object. Descriptions go by `dev1.x`, where x can be a different number or letter or whatever, doesn't matter.

**What I want to do:**

I'm trying to reorder `$result` into the format below. Pretty much, by traversing each item in the `$result` array, each `description` in result will be it's own property in a new object. Inside of each `description` property will be subitems like `id`, `sum`, `completed_pct_completed`, etc. It will look like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[dev1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 182
                [1] => 218
                [2] => 218
                [3] => 021
                [4] => 186
                [5] => 287
                [6] => 21A
            )

        [sum] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
        [completed_pct_completed] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
        [completed_pct_1msec] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
            .........

    )

[dev1.1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 182
                [1] => 329
                [2] => 465
                [3] => 685
                [4] => 686
                [5] => 607
                [6] => 61A
            )

        [sum] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
        [completed_pct_completed] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
        [completed_pct_1msec] => Array
            (
                [0] => 567
                [1] => 567
                [2] => 567
                [3] => 567
                [4] => 567
                [5] => 567
                [6] => 567
            )
         ............
       )
       ............
```

**What I've done so far**

So here's how I've constructed what I want so far:

I made an object with properties of each unique description:

```
$object = new STDClass();
//$flipped is the transposed version of $result, then I got unique names
foreach (array_unique($flipped['description']) as $string)
    $object->{$string} = array();
```

This went perfectly fine. Then, I added the subitems to each description property in `$object`

```
$dummyObject = new STDClass();
foreach ($object as $objectKey=>$objectValue) {
    foreach ($result[0] as $key=>$value){
        if ($key!='description'){
            $dummyObject->{$key}=array();
            $object->$objectKey=$dummyObject;
        }
    }
}
```

This also went fine.

The problem here is inserting the data into each `id` and `summary`, etc.. Here's what I've done:

```
//add data to the subitems
//foreach dev1.x => array
foreach ($object as $key => $nextObject)
{
    //foreach array as subitems(id, board, etc.) => array
    foreach ($nextObject as $nextKey => $dataArray)
    {
        $dummyArray = array();
        foreach ($result as $array)
        {
            foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue)
            {
                if ($array->{'description'} == $key) {
                    if ($nextKey == $arrayKey) {
                        $dummyArray[]=$arrayValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $object->{$key}->{$nextKey} = $dummyArray;
    }
}
```

In the end, all the data from the last `dev1.x` property ends up being overwritten into every single `dev1.x` property. I've tried adding `break;` in multiple places hoping that I'd be able to deduce what is going wrong. I have a gut feeling that there's more going on than I know with the `foreach` statements. Would anyone mind helping me with this?

Thanks

Comment: based on input values what expected outcome you want? Aslo add some more values to input an address them too in the expected outcome.

Comment: @Anant, I added more. Is this sufficient?

Comment: No. You didn't say where/how $result[0] is populated from. Since I doubt you're defining the object in code, it means you are extracting it from a database. In which case the right solution is to populate it into the structure you need *at the point where it comes out of the database* - not the wrong structure and then converting it. Fix the right problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create keys while iterating:

```
$data = new stdClass();
foreach ($result as $object) {
    $description = $object->description;
    isset($data->{$description}) or $data->{$description} = new stdClass();

    foreach ($object as $name => $value) {
        if ($name === 'description') { continue; }
        $data->{$description}->{$name}[] = $value;
    }
}
```

I don't like descriptions as field names though. Access to `$data->{'dev1.1'}` is ugly. Would pack it into an array of objects, but description property would be just a string and other properties would be aggregated arrays. It would need some changes in procedure (index of descriptions propably).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be less complicated than it seems. Unless I'm misunderstanding what the transformation should be, you can do it like this:

```
foreach ($result as $obj) {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'description') {
            $new_result->{$obj->description}->$key[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This should create the object and add the appropriate properties and values all at once.

The reason you're getting the duplication is in this part:

```
$dummyObject = new STDClass();
foreach ($object as $objectKey=>$objectValue) {
    foreach ($result[0] as $key=>$value){
        if ($key!='description'){
            $dummyObject->{$key}=array();
            $object->$objectKey=$dummyObject;
        }
    }
}
```

When you do `$object->$objectKey=$dummyObject;` because you created the object before the loop, you're resetting and reassigning *the same object* to each `$objectKey`. So when you fill it with values later, you just end up with multiple copies of whatever the last one was. If you use a copy of the object insteady (`$object->$objectKey= clone $dummyObject;`) it should work. But it does seem a bit overcomplicated.